# Braintree + Python: Configure credential at transaction level rather than module

Tags: python, braintree

I am currently using Python to integrate with Braintree. At the module-level, we configure our API keys. From the doc:

```
import braintree
braintree.Configuration.configure(...)

def my_transaction():
    braintree.Transaction.sale(...)
```

How can I configure braintree at the method level? That is, if I wanted to use a different credential for each transaction, how could I do so without updating a global config? Eg:

```
import braintree

def my_transaction():
    braintree.Transaction.sale({
        'configuration': {...},
        'amount': ...
    })
```

I would like to be able to use a different API key, depending on the source of the transaction. I would also like to be able to more easily toggle between Sandbox and Production credentials.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Configuration objects [can be instantiated](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python/blob/master/tests/unit/test_configuration.py#L10):

```
config = braintree.Configuration(
    environment=braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
    merchant_id='my_merchant_id',
    public_key='public_key',
    private_key='private_key'
)
```

and passed to a [Braintree gateway object](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python/blob/master/braintree/braintree_gateway.py#L16):

```
gateway = braintree.BraintreeGateway(config)
```

which you can then [use to run transactions](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python/blob/master/braintree/transaction_gateway.py#L31):

```
result = gateway.transaction.create({'amount': ...})
```

So you can either instantiate a new gateway for each transaction with the appropriate credentials, or keep around a gateway with each set of credentials and use the appropriate one.

Comment: That is excellent - thank you! I was digging into the library's source and hadn't quite put the pieces together. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, this code doesn't quite work! I believe there is a bug in the current version (2.26.0) of the library. `AttributeError: type object 'Configuration' has no attribute 'use_unsafe_ssl'`. However, I can file a bug or pull request in github. Looks like this code path doesn't really have tests. But this gets me started, thank you again!

Comment: @poundifdef Yeah, I noticed that there weren't any tests when I was writing this answer. That there is a bug due to that missing coverage is not good. I'll try and fix it in the next couple of days. Filing a pull request or issue on Github is a great way to help us track the problem, thanks!