# Django-RQ + Braintree: Submit for settlement

Tags: django, braintree, python-rq, django-rq

I have read this stackoverflow [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237863/braintree-python-configure-credential-at-transaction-level-rather-than-module) but it did not worked it my case.

In my scenario I push a function (`submit_transaction_for_settlement(transaction_id)`) to the redis queue using the excellent package [`django-rq`](https://github.com/ui/django-rq). The job of this function is to submit a transaction for settlement.

In the sandbox, whenever this function is executed I keep getting the same error: `AttributeError: type object 'Configuration' has no attribute 'environment'`.

I tried [`agf`'s proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237863/braintree-python-configure-credential-at-transaction-level-rather-than-module#answer-21263451) about `instantiate a new gateway for each transaction` inside my function, but it did not work!

Maybe this has something to do with the environment of the redis queue or the worker environment?

```
def submit_transaction_for_settlement(transaction_id):
    from braintree import Configuration, BraintreeGateway

    config = Configuration(environment=settings.BRAINTREE_ENVIRONMENT, merchant_id=settings.BRAINTREE_MERCHANT_ID,
                                   public_key=settings.BRAINTREE_PUBLIC_KEY, private_key=settings.BRAINTREE_PRIVATE_KEY)
    gateway = BraintreeGateway(config=config)
    result = gateway.transaction.submit_for_settlement(transaction_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahrg!

I hate the moments where I answer a question and minutes after I find myself the solution!

The fault was in the command running the [`rqworker`](https://github.com/ui/django-rq#usage). I was using the command `python manage.py rqworker --worker-class rq.SimpleWorker` because I had [this issue](https://github.com/ui/django-rq/issues/123) because I used python 2.7 (or something else caused this issue). The command generated this issue was `python manage.py rqworker`.

Upgrading now to python 3.4, the last command works like a charm!
So, running `python manage.py rqworker` did the trick and no such errors!